# VSTO MailItem.Recipients retrieve email addresses in C#

Tags: c#, email, vsto, mailitem

Background information: I am writing an addin program for Outlook in C#. When a user senda an email in outlook I want to get the email addresses listed in the to, cc and bcc text boxes. As a test I am attempting to print the first recipients email address in a new window.

```
private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {

            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

            Outlook.Recipients myRecipients = mailItem.Recipients;

            MessageBox.Show(myRecipients(0));
    }
}
```

Microsoft docs Recipients Interface states "Use Recipients(index), where index is the name or index number, to return a single Recipient object. However, the myRecipients(0) call gives me an error which states Method name expected.

I believe I have properly initialized the Recipients collection as I have been able to call myRecipients.Count which returns the correct number of recipients listed in a draft email.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually a collection item can be accessed by passing the indexer within square brackets (not round brackets as you have in the code in your question)... In the case of `Outlook.Recipients` however I think the collection does not implement this pattern and therefore you need to use the [`Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.item) method like this `myRecipients.Item(0)` where `0` is your index.